# Type conversion in C#, Explicit casting to int and Convert.ToInt32

Tags: c#, types

In my following code

```
long Price = 148920000;
long PRICE = 1000000;
double Multiplier = 100.00;
int Value = (int)(((double)Price / PRICE) * Multiplier);
```

I expect Value as 14892 but in C# it is coming 14891....

Comment: Please never use variable names that only differ in casing, unless you are in an obfuscated code contest.

Comment: Use decimal if you want precise values  http://ideone.com/TFA2q5 This is worth reading : http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Decimal.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar on how to get the values that you want to convert this answer will give you what you are looking for

```
long Price = 148920000;
long PRICE = 1000000;
double Multiplier = 100.00;
var Value = (Convert.ToInt32(Math.Round((double)Price / (double)PRICE) * Multiplier));
```

or 
a another version without using `var` keyword yields the same results

```
long Price = 148920000;
long PRICE = 1000000;
double Multiplier = 100.00;
int Value = (int)(Math.Round((double)Price / (double)PRICE) * Multiplier);
```

`Answer = 14892`

Answer (score 4):

Floating-point arithmetic id ALWAYS approximate. Use one of Math.Round(), Math.Floor(), or Math.Ceiling() to control how doubles/floats are converted to any int type. Or look at using Decimal instead.

Answer (score 0):

not on a development machine at the mo but can you try this?

```
long Price = 148920000;
long PRICE = 1000000;
double Multiplier = 100.00;
checked
{
int Value = (int)(((double)Price / PRICE) * Multiplier);
}
```

should throw an error if it overflows

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/74b4xzyw(v=vs.71).aspx